# Behavior of "created on" and "updated on" database fields

Tags: sql, database, datetime, database-design, sql-null

In general, it is a good practice to use *"**created on**"* and *"**updated on**"* columns for SQL database tables for traceability reasons, exact we you have some other way of tracing the database record changes.

For *"created on"* column it's obvious that it should be set only at table's row / record insertion, but what about the *"updated on"* column?

1. Is it better to set it also at record insertion, along with the *"created on"* column?

   - Cons: The *"updated on"* column is set also at record creation, which can be misleading, since it wasn't updated yet, only created.
   - Pros: Both fields can be defined as non-`null`. You can query just on the *”updated on”* column if you want to filter by updated and created records indistinguishably.
2. Is it better to leave it's value to be `null` at record insertion, and set it only at table's row update?

   - Cons: *"updated on"* column can't be defined as non-`null`.
   - Benefits: The *"updated on"* column is set to `null` at record creation, which signifies the record hasn't been updated yet, only created, hence we don’t need to check the *”created on”* column as well, in such case.

There might be other approaches to handling this, which are also welcome to discuss.

I'm suspecting the choice between the options is subjective, but want to see if there are some unwritten rules or guidelines about this matter, since I couldn't find any. Other considerations and comments are welcome as well!

Comment: I've always set the updated timestamp to be the same as the created timestamp.  You can tell a row hasn't been updated if the timestamps are the same.  Plus, you can query just on the updated timestamp if you want all updates and creates.

Comment: Note that table have _columns_, not fields. (And a timestamp has a year _field_, a month _field_, etc.)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc of course you can compare them to check if the record has been updated, but if the update column can be ‘null’, you need to check this only against this column. For the same reason I like your note about querying all updates and creates. Adding it to the OP.